# Can't push to remote repository in github

Tags: github, push, pull

I'm new to github so for the sake of testing I've been modifying my .gitconfig file (adding some useful aliases, etc.) and pushing it to my "Config Files" repository on github.

I have 2 computers, a desktop and a laptop. When I modify the local file in the desktop, commit and push to the remote repository it works fine.

However, when I try to do the same from the laptop I get this error.

```
     ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/User/Config-Files.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Aditionally I get this error if I try to pull first like the message suggests:

```
$ git pull origin master
remote: Enumerating objects: 6, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 2), reused 4 (delta 2), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), 355 bytes | 8.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://github.com/User/Config-Files
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   627ab06..b327e2b  master     -> origin/master
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

The remote repository only has the .gitconfig file, the same file I'm trying to push from the laptop so why am I getting this error?

Comment: Q: Have you considered trying what the message suggests, and doing a git pull?

Comment: Yes, I updated the main post with the error I get as well.

Comment: To elaborate: 1) `fetch` gets your remote changes; `pull` does a fetch, and also commits the changes. 2) In your case, you made changes to both your desktop and your laptop independently.  This created a "conflict", so you *couldn't* just pull.  Git told you so. 3)  As Adam Noah explained so well, one option would have been to use `--force`.  4) As he explained equally well, a *better* option was to resolve the conflict with a fetch, then merge.  ANYWAY - glad you got it working!  Please "upvote" his answer (in addition to "accepting" it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your terminal, it is telling you to fetch first.

You pushed to master already from your desktop, and your commit on your laptop is behind. So you have to fetch, merge, and then you'll be able to push from your laptop..

This is bad practice but can always force it in.. (`--force`) but then any of the changes made on your desktop would be gone.

Comment: I'd like to have a backup of my config files for all the dev tools I use on github, so I could download them if I need them on another computer.

Can I update a file without having to clone the whole repository to my computer? (that's why I was getting that error). Forcing the update without cloning first replaces the whole repository with the single file I'm updating.